# Deploy Jhispter Spring Boot as a Linux (Debian) Service

Tags: spring-boot, service, debian, jhipster

I have been installing Jhispter has a service in a Debian Linux and working ok.

Now I upgrade and produce the nms4.jar with:

```
 ./mvnw -Pprod clean verify
```

If I do

```
sudo /usr/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/nms-api/nms4.jar
```

Runs the nms4.jar and works great!
https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8020

But if I do

```
sudo service nms4 start
```

Says:

```
Job for nms4.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nms4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And:

```
sudo systemctl status nms4.service
● nms4.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nms4; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-18 16:44:44 UTC; 3h 20min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 16656 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nms4 start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 18 16:44:44 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: Starting nms4.service...
Sep 18 16:44:44 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Sep 18 16:44:44 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: Failed to start nms4.service.
Sep 18 16:44:44 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 18 16:44:44 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
timmeh55@nms-cp01-vm01:~$ sudo service nms4 start
Job for nms4.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nms4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
timmeh55@nms-cp01-vm01:~$ sudo systemctl status nms4.service
● nms4.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nms4; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-09-18 20:05:52 UTC; 14s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 19899 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nms4 start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 18 20:05:52 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: Starting nms4.service...
Sep 18 20:05:52 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Sep 18 20:05:52 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: Failed to start nms4.service.
Sep 18 20:05:52 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Unit entered failed state.
Sep 18 20:05:52 nms-cp01-vm01 systemd[1]: nms4.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
timmeh55@nms-cp01-vm01:~$ sudo /usr/bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/nms-api/nms4.jar
```

In my pom.xml I have set:

```
<embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
    <mode>service</mode>
</embeddedLaunchScriptProperties>
```

And did:

```
cd /etc/init.d
sudo chown nmsapi:nmsapi /var/lib/nms-api/nms4.jar
sudo chmod +x /var/lib/nms-api/nms4.jar
sudo ln -s /var/lib/nms-api/nms4.jar /etc/init.d/nms4
sudo systemctl enable nms4
```

generator-jhipster@6.3.0

How can I solve this?

Info:

```
  ##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**


<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.gotop.nms",
      "nativeLanguage": "en"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "6.3.0",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "baseName": "nms",
    "packageName": "com.gotop.nms",
    "packageFolder": "com/gotop/nms",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "enableHibernateCache": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "bXktc2VjcmV0LXRva2VuLXRvLWNoYW5nZS1pbi1wcm9kdWN0aW9uLWFuZC10by1rZWVwLWluLWEtc2VjdXJlLXBsYWNl",
    "embeddableLaunchScript": false,
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "otherModules": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": ["en", "nl"],
    "blueprints": []
  }
}
```

Is giving:
Write protection error:

```
sudo tail -n 500 /var/log/nms4.log
2019-09-21 07:04:48.878 ERROR 15511 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring.log (Permission denied)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at com.gotop.nms.NmsApp.main(NmsApp.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring.log (Permission denied)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at com.gotop.nms.NmsApp.main(NmsApp.java:63)
    ... 8 more
timmeh55@nms-cp01-vm01:~$ sudo tail -n 1000 /var/log/nms4.log
2019-09-21 07:04:48.878 ERROR 15511 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring.log (Permission denied)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at com.gotop.nms.NmsApp.main(NmsApp.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/spring.log (Permission denied)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:167)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:289)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:264)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:226)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:342)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at com.gotop.nms.NmsApp.main(NmsApp.java:63)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: How you created nms4.service ?

Comment: @Yogesh Prajapati with ./mvnw -Pprod clean verify

Comment: No, I am talking about service nms4.service? "./mvnw -Pprod clean verify" This will not create service on OS, right ?

Comment: In JHipster v6.3 we disabled the embedable jar launch script by default : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10282/files#diff-46af807fe730aba11ead7c88e7e79a31L872

Comment: Thanks a lot @PierreBesson! Is working! Was giving write protection error ( /tmp/spring.log -rw-r--r-- 1 root root ). I did chown nmsapi:nmsapi  /tmp/spring.log chmod +x  /tmp/spring.log. I will accept your answer, but would like just to know if this is the best to do regarding /tmp/spring.log file?

Comment: Your logback-spring.xml is including org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml. That, in turn, includes Boot's default file appender configuration which writes to /tmp/spring.log by default. I would recommend you write your own logback-spring.xml to take control of your logs.The usual way is to log to /var/log/nms4/nms4.log this way you can have easy file permissions for log rotation in /var/log/nms4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the Spring Boot embedable launch script. Make sure that the following is set in your pom :

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
    <executable>true</executable>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue in past.

You are gettng permission denied because "/tmp/spring.log" is already present and has root:root as owner and group.

Either delete or change ownership of /tmp/spring.log.

spring.log is already exist because you may have prior run jar using root user.